# learning angular dart and using angular gallery section library

Tags: angular, dart, web-deployment, angular-dart

I have been learning Angular Dart since about 3 weeks ago but I'm having really a hard time with it specially that the learning resources for this new language are really limited.
Anyway, my problem is I can't import any thing from the " angular gallery section " library.
like when I try:

```
import'package:angular_gallery_section/annotation/gallery_section_config.dart';
```

or

```
import 'package:angular_gallery_section/annotation/gallery_section_config.dart';
```

so I can't import any thing from angular_gallery_section library (there is always an error)

I tried to adjust ' pubspec.yaml ' file like this:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.1.0-dev.5.0 <3.0.0'

# angular_gallery:
#   arget: ":angular_gallery"
#   import: "package:angular_gallery/builders.dart"
#   builder_factories: [galleryAppBuilder, galleryLibBuilder, syntaxHighlightBuilder]
#   build_extensions: {
#     ".html": [".dart"],
#     "$web$": ["index.html", "main.dart", "style.scss"]}

dependencies:
  angular: ^5.1.0
  # angular_gallery_section:
  #    path: ../../angular_gallery_sections
  angular_forms: ^2.1.0
  async: ^2.0.8
  build: '>=0.11.1 <2.0.0'
  build_config: '>=0.2.6 <0.4.0'
  built_collection: ^4.0.0
  collection: ^1.14.10
  angular_components: '>=0.9.0 <=0.10.0'
  angular_router: ^2.0.0-alpha+19
  sass_builder: ^2.0.2  
  intl: '>=0.14.0 <0.16.0'
  glob: ^1.1.5
  markdown: ^2.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  path: ^1.6.1
  test: ^1.0.0
  build_web_compilers: '>=0.3.6 <0.5.0'
  build_runner: '>=0.8.10 <2.0.0'
```

but the problem haven't been solved yet, the path for the angular_gallery_section isn't working so I think I really missed up :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
  # angular_gallery_section:
  #    path: ../../angular_gallery_sections
```

add

```
  angular_gallery_section:
    git: 
      url: git@github.com:dart-lang/angular_components_example.git
      path: angular_gallery_section
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer..
it tells me that:
" Resolving dependencies...
Cannot find a Git executable.
Please ensure Git is correctly installed. "
There is something still missing.
I tried to change ' git@github.com:dart-lang/angular_components_example.git '
to 'git@github.com:dart-lang/angular_components.git'
I also got the same result.

Comment: You need to have https://git-scm.com/download/win installed (if you use Windows) and ensure `git` is found in the path.

Comment: if i downloaded the angular_gallery_section and put it in a folder to my project.
can I use the path to refer to it instead of using git ?

Comment: Yes, but ensure the path is correct (`angular_gallery_sections` vs `angular_gallery_section` - singular)